# Slider in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to use the **slider** in windows phone 7.

But i am not sure how to get the value of the slider stop point.

I wanted something like this slider **minimum value to be 1**.

And the **maximum value to be 10**.

Then when the **slider stop at one point** example 5.
Den i will have a text block showing the value of the stop point.

How should i go about doing it? I tried the below code but still not working.

```
private void MinimumRangeSpan_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double value = 0;
    double.TryParse(this.minimumRangeSpan.Text, out value);
    this.rangeSlider.MinimumRangeSpan = value;
}
```

I just needed a simple slider that can get the stop point of the slider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely you mean the *value* of the Slider? So something as simple, as doing a direct binding to the sliders Value should do the trick?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=MySlider}" />
```

But I don't consider a slider to be a very good UI element for a mobile phone. You should strongly consider alternatives, such as a [LoopingSelector](http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/using-loopingselector-from-the-silverlight-toolkit)

Comment: Because i am trying to do something like they can adjust the volumne. But then i found out that the value is in decimal place can it be changed to whole number??

Comment: You can typecast it. If you need formatting with a direct binding like here, write a ValueConverter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)